# SQL Server - keep restarting EXEC as long as dependent job completes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, procedure

I need to automate element in my backups schedule for differential copies.
DIFF must be performed only when job_a is not running.

The only moment when below code clashes with job_a is when job_a may be still running in scheduled time for job_b to start. I need some pattern to keep re-running job_b till job_a won't be returned by first `NOT EXISTS`

I did a test where job_a starts run one second before job_b. While job_b should be trying to restart as long as job_a disappears from system logs, it abandons the retries.

```
IF NOT EXISTS 

        (SELECT job.name FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view job
        INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity activity ON job.job_id = activity.job_id
        INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.syssessions sess ON sess.session_id = activity.session_id
        INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(agent_start_date) AS max_agent_start_date FROM msdb.dbo.syssessions) sess_max ON sess.agent_start_date = sess_max.max_agent_start_date

        WHERE run_requested_date IS NOT NULL 
        AND stop_execution_date IS NULL
        AND job.name = 'job_a')

    BEGIN
        DECLARE @path_diff varchar(max)
        SET @path_diff = 'H:\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\dev\db_name' + CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 112) + REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 114),':','') + '_DIFF_COMP.BAK'
        BACKUP DATABASE [db_name] TO DISK = @path_diff WITH COMPRESSION, DIFFERENTIAL , STATS = 10
    END

--need a step that will re-start the job once job_a doesn't appear in NOT EXISTS
ELSE 
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_stop_job  N'job_b'
    PRINT 'Full backup is taking longer then usual, please inspect!'
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job  N'job_b'
```

Comment: Aside: You might want to consider a solution that uses an _application lock_ to allow one job to wait for another to finish. See [sp_getapplock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for more information.